# How to play a video in mpeg-ts container format with H.264 encoding in a Flex 4 application?

Tags: apache-flex, video-streaming, h.264, mpeg2-ts

I am trying to create a Flex 4 application to stream video in mpeg-ts format. The video is encoded in H.264 and the audio in mp3/AAC. I am unable to figure out the approach I should take. Is it possible to download mpeg-ts chunks and then play it in Flex. Any suggestions/help  appreciated.

Thanks,
Soumya

Comment: if you want to *stream* video, you need a *streaming* server.

Comment: I am trying to build something so that I can support Apple's HLS instead of using a streaming server like Flash Media Server. I need to download the mpeg-ts chunks and stitch them together in Flex so that it plays smoothly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of using mpeg-ts, flv can be used as the container for the specified codecs. It would work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend looking at Red5, Wowza, or Flash Media Server.  These are excellent applications that can stream just about anything to flash in a very high performance manner.  Red5 is free.  Both have extensive documentation and examples.

Comment: I wanted to avoid RTMP based streaming. I want to primarily focus on http based streaming technologies. Http pseudostreaming also seems an option.

Comment: Flash Media Server 4.5 does http streaming and dynamic (adaptive) http streaing using auto switching between different bitrate streams.